# How to type/send hex on a PuTTY session

Tags: putty

I'm using PuTTY to make a serial connection to a device. I need to send a hexadecimal string on this session. How do I do this?

The hexadecimal string is `FF7E414244`.

This is required to break the serial device into command interface mode...

From an Windows XP machine, I can use HyperTerminal. And then on the serial connection, do a "send file", where the file has this hexadecimal string entered using hex editing means. So this mechanism works.

But now I have a Windows 7 with no HyperTerminal. So I'm using PuTTY. But now how do I send the hex string?

Comment: are you sure sending a "break" won't accomplish the same thing? if you right click on the title bar of your putty session you can do a send special and this is one of the options.

Comment: No its not the same as sending a "break".  I want to send this specific hex string over on the serial connection and I have a win7 machine.  So since I cant use hyperterminal, is there any other way to do it? (using putty or any other mechanism?)

Comment: Have you tried Kermit? http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/k95faq.html  It works on windows 7(according to the docs) and has send file support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can not be done with PuTTY. Use [Tera Term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tera_Term) instead. Make sure you send in "Binary" mode - there's a checkbox for it when sending a file using Tera Term.

Comment: The logging functionality (File > Log) is useful too for examining answers – again, check binary mode there.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use RealTerm which is even better than TeraTerm, which is already good